# Get a reference to the same object like getLogger does

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I'm working on a CLI tool in Python. I have big structure file in JSON that I parsed via a `DataStructure` class.

Once it is done, it passes around this object between all my classes in the project. This is a bit annoying, I was wondering if anyone knew how to a reference to an object just like the `logging` library does, using `logging.getLogger()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a module, for example called `data`, and inside it define a function that returns a global variable.  For example, `data.py`:

```
_impl = None

def get():
    if _impl is None:
        _impl = SomethingThatMakesTheData()
    return _impl
```

Then you can `import data` and do `data.get()` from wherever you need.

Comment: Brilliant. I did the following: from services import DataStructureHelper

implDsh = None

def getDsh():
    global implDsh
    if implDsh is None:
        implDsh = DataStructureHelper.DataStructureHelper()
    return implDsh

def setDsh():
    global implDsh
    implDsh = DataStructureHelper.DataStructureHelper()
    return implDsh

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
class DataStructure:

    @classmethod
    def parsinglogic(cls):
        ##Define JSON parsing logic here
        data=json.loads('filename')
        return data
```

`DataStructure.parsinglogic()` can be used to call JSON parser.See each time this is called ,JSON file is read.

Instead create instance method and an instance variable to store the value and pass it to the other classes.

```
import json
class DataStructure:
    def __init__(self,data=None):
        self.data=data

    def parsinglogic(self):
        ##Define JSON parsing logic here
        self.data=json.loads('filename')
        return self.data


d=DataStructure()
data=d.parsinglogic()
#Pass this data to the other classes
```